# Why is my bath hot water not so hot now that I have new taps?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I have had new taps fitted in my bathroom, both bath and sink. However when I have a bath the hot water is not as hot as it is for the sink or indeed downstairs in the kitchen.
I don't have to use any cold in the bath, and it seemed hotter before I replaced the taps

What can this be?

Answer (score 1):

In general (which is all we can do without specifics of "what new taps") bath and shower controls in the current era include an "anti-scald" feature which deliberately limits how hot the water coming out can be (by some means, which vary, and with more or less effectiveness...)

If replacing older taps, this may well reduce the maximum temperature you can get by a noticeable degree (pun works but not actually intended...)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of tap, your hot could be restricted.  Many taps will have an adjustment screw that will change how much water comes out when it is fully open.  If you have reduced flow from the hot or excess flow from the cold this can make the mixture of hot and cold go too heavily towards cold.